# How to use MaterialSearchView On Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to add [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) with Custom Toolbar inside a fragment.

So first I created the xml layout for it.

search_view.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I added the menu Item..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
            app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
            />
    </menu>
```

Then in fragment class I added the custom actionbar. And after testing it the code worked fine. But when I added the MaterialSearchView .. The application stops responding..

So here is my java code..

```
    public class searchView extends Fragment{

        Toolbar search;
        MaterialSearchView search_view;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view,container,false);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view, container, false);

           search = (Toolbar)layout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(search);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contacts");

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)  {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.search,menu);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
            search_view = (MaterialSearchView) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
            final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            search_view.setMenuItem(item);
        }
    }
```

The complete error log is so big.. So here is some part

```
   01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.initiateView(MaterialSearchView.java:143)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:93)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:85)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(Native method)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0cb4b03a> (a java.lang.Object[])
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.initiateView(MaterialSearchView.java:143)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:93)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:85)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(Native method)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    01-17 19:46:57.968 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0cb4b03a> (a java.lang.Object[])
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.initiateView(MaterialSearchView.java:143)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:93)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView.<init>(MaterialSearchView.java:85)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(Native method)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    01-17 19:46:57.969 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]   Summary:
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]       503 of com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView (503 unique instances)
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]         1 of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]         1 of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]         4 of java.lang.String (4 unique instances)
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]         2 of java.lang.Class (2 unique instances)
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427]         1 of java.lang.String[] (4 elements)
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427] 
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:427] 
01-17 19:46:58.178 17920-17920/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 17920 (buckydroid.chat)

                                         [ 01-17 19:46:58.178   357:  357 W/         ]
                                         debuggerd: handling request: pid=17920 uid=10147 gid=10147 tid=17920
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Change

```
 search_view = (MaterialSearchView) getView().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

to

```
 search_view = (MaterialSearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

My code for example

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `setHasOptionsMenu` in your Fragment like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Comment: Also added the error log.. Its so big ... So I am able to add the part of it